# How many Spark JavaRDDs are ideal to process thousands of files?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am having thousands of files to process and it resides in HDFS. I have working solution as shown below but I would like to know best practices for idea RDDs count. Currently I use only one RDD which points to thousands of files in HDFS.

```
    //the following line contains comma separated files to process
        String fileToProcessList = "/user/server1/server.dat,/user/server2/server2.dat";
    JavaRDD<Record> rdd_records = sc.textFile(filetoProcessList).map(
      new Function<String, Record>() {
          public Record call(String line) throws Exception {
             String[] fields = line.split(",");
             Record sd = new Record(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2].trim(), fields[3]);
             return sd;
      }
});
```

Do I need to use more JavaRDD in above case or one is fine even in case of millions of files? One thing I noticed is there is no parallelism: I see it processes files sequentially even if I use 12 executors on master yarn.

Comment: HI user449355,Only 1 RDD is required.When the size of RDD increases the number of partitions in the rdd increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDDs could be seen as a pointer to the data that allows to define operations over that data. Those operations are scheduled on executors in a cluster.

Given the same amount of resources (cluster size, mem - cpu), whether your RDD points to a small or a big dataset will only impact the time it takes to process the data. If you foresee that the data size will increase, you need to determine whether:

- it's acceptable to wait longer for the results => then do nothing
- the allotted time is fixed => then increase cluster resources

In a nutshell, one RDD definition is fine. Tune your cluster resources according to dataset size and business requirements for the results.

Answer (score 0):

First up, if your HDFS has thousands of smallish files, your upstream application is not doing things while writings. In that case, consider writing a input format to combine files (or look into hadoop's input formats to see if something suits you). 
Secondly, if you have really big files, go through Sandy Ryza's awesome [blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/) at cloudera site about tuning cluster resources.